# Bad text rendering for mulitple monitors in WPF app with Direct2D

Tags: .net, wpf, directx, dpi, direct2d

I am having a problem with very bad text rendering in the Direct2D sections of a WPF app.

The dev who knew about this stuff recently left, and now I'm stuck trying to figure it out.

Background:
I have a large 1920x1080 external monitor that is my default monitor. In Windows settings, the "Scale" is set to 100%. This monitor is connected to my laptop, which is also 1920x1080, but much smaller. The "Scale" is set to 125% for this monitor.

The application is a WPF app, and we used DirectX11 in parts of the app.

Problem 1:
I startup the app on my default external monitor and the text in the charts rendered by Direct2D looks great.
[image: Pic1]

I drag the app over to my laptop screen, and the text gets blocky.
[image: Pic2]

Problem 2:
If I startup the app on my laptop screen, the text is very small compared to the rest of the application text.
[image: Pic3]

And when I drag this back over to my external monitor, the text remains small and looks absolutely awful and blocky.
[image: Pic4]

The blockiness does not seem to be limited to the text - the lines also exhibit this same weird texture.

Some settings:
I know the previous developer added some lines to the app.manifest to try to make the app DPI-aware.

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitor</dpiAwareness>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
```

Removing the `<dpiAwareness>` PerMonitor line fixes Problem #1, but it creates fuzzy text for the situation described in Problem #2, and doesn't fix the small text aspect of Problem #2.

Another possibly suspect piece of code for Problem #2's small text is the creation of the DirectX `FontResource11`. I'm not sure where the numbers come from in the `fontSizeDips` calculation??

```
internal FontResouce11(DeviceEngine11 d3dEngine, SharpDX.DirectWrite.Factory factory, string familyName, float fontSize, int fontHeight, bool isBold)
        {
            if (factory == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(factory));
            if (familyName == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(familyName));
            _writeFactory = factory;
            _d3dEngine = d3dEngine;
            FontWeight weight;
            if (isBold)
            {
                weight = FontWeight.Bold;
            }
            else
            {
                weight = FontWeight.Normal;
            }

            float fontSizeDips = fontSize / 72.0F * 96.0F;

            // Create a format using the font size and weight.
            _format = new TextFormat(_writeFactory, familyName, weight, SharpDX.DirectWrite.FontStyle.Normal, fontSizeDips);
            _height = fontHeight;
        }
```

Maybe I need to be grabbing the DPI somewhere in here and using it to set the `fontSizeDips`?

I don't have much of an idea what I'm looking for or doing, and any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: DPI handling principles are detailed here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows. If you don't declare anything (no manifest), you're "unaware", so Windows will bitmap-stretch what your app renders (=> blurry at best). If you declare you're aware, you *must* change your code so it adapts to DPI context. It can be quite complex and only depends on your code exclusively. Difficult to understand what parts are displayed by WPF vs Direct2D vs Directx11 in what you describe (WPF is generally not DPI aware). Or post a repro project.

Comment: Yeah, I've read that and it's not super helpful for DirectX stuff. Seems like I am declaring I'm aware but the code isn't handling that correctly. As far as what is displayed by what - I'm not very knowledgeable but we have some sort of viewer embedded in the WPF to show these charts, and inside that is all DirectX11. I think all the chart stuff shown is rendered with Direct2D.

Comment: They are the same principle with Direct2D: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-and-high-dpi

Comment: Sure, but again, these documents don't really help me much. I understand that I need to make some changes in the code to support the DPI awareness, but I don't really know where to start.